# is there a way to get the attribute text directly in a xml without traversing through children in elementree in python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am using the `python module :  xml.etree.ElementTree`  for parsing xml files.
I am curious to know if there is a way to directly find an attribute that is nested deeply.
For example if I want to get the `name attribute` of neigbhor (if it exists),
I need to traverse through `country/rank/year/gdppc`, if my root is `data`. Is there a quick way to look up that attribute?

```
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>
           <year>
                 <gdppc>
                       <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
                 </gdppc>
           </year>
         </rank>
    </country>
</data>
```

EDIT:
I tried something on this line. but did not help; I am not sure if I should be using `resp.content` for the `xml` retrived

```
resp=requests.get(url_fetch,params=query)    
    with open(resp.content) as fd:
        doc = ElementTree.parse(fd)
        name = doc.find('PubmedArticle//Volume').text
        print name
```

here is the [xml:](http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=24059499&retmode=xml)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your data looks like and exactly what you're trying to accomplish, you could do something like this:

```
with open('data.xml') as fd:
    doc = ElementTree.parse(fd)
    name = doc.find('country[@name="Liechtenstein"]//neighbor').get('name')
    print name
```

Which given the input above would yield:

```
Austria
```

If you're parsing XML with Python, you may want to look at the `lxml` module, which has full support for XPath queries.

This works for me with the URL you gave above:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests
from xml.etree import ElementTree

res = requests.get('http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=24059499&retmode=xml')
doc = ElementTree.fromstring(res.content)
ele = doc.find('.//PubmedArticle//Volume')
print ele.text
```

Comment: please see my edit above: I am trying to parse the xml which I have given above using what you suggested. but when I run it, it takes for-ever and so I have to do a keyboard interrupt

Comment: great this worked! but why do you have `.//Pubmed//Volume` instead of `PubmedArticle//Volume`

Comment: Artifact of some testing that I was doing.  Either will work.

Comment: having `.//PubmedArticle//Volume` means from the current node locate a first direct child which is `pubmedArticle` and locate its first direct child `Volume`. am I correct?